# Как передать цену в Яндекс кассу?

Tags: php, яндекс-касса

Вот кусок кода, где я прописываю цену в соответсвующий параметр:

```
$payment = $client->createPayment(
        array(
            'amount' => array(
                'value' => 15000.0, // тут пишу цену
                'currency' => 'RUB',
            ),
            'confirmation' => array(
                'type' => 'redirect',
                'return_url' => 'https://mysite.ru',
            ),
            'capture' => true,
            'description' => 'Покупка'
    ),
    uniqid('', true)
    );
```

Допустим у меня есть интернет-магазин где много разных товаров с разными ценами. Как мне передать цену товара в кассу? Или как ее конфигурировать чтобы в кассу передавалась именно цена товара?

Допустим зашел на страницу "Товар 1", вижу его цену 100 руб. Нажал купить, перешел в кассу и там цена 100 руб. Зашел на страницу "Товар 2", его цена 200 руб, Нажал купить, перешел на кассу и там цена 200 руб.

Comment: Ну просто прописывайте вместо 15000.0 любое нужное вам значение, не? В чём проблема-то?

Comment: @andreymal видимо сложно при каждой оплате руками прописывать

Comment: @РашенБеар ну представьте на сайте 1000 товаров, для каждого своя касса?